# Weak Event Pattern in MonoTouch

Tags: ios, events, weak-references, xamarin.ios

I used to develop iOS apps using the Objective-C language, and relied on the `dealloc` method to perform some cleanup/unregister tasks in my application. Now on the MonoTouch (garbage collected) it is not an option anymore.

Suppose I have a `UIViewController` that adds as a subview of it's `View` property an instance of `MyView` (`UIView` subclass). `MyView` in turn registers itself to receive some events from another manager/global object so that it knows how to update itself accordingly (e.g.: `onlineProfilesManager.Refreshed += () => <update UI with the new state>;`).

As long as `MyView` is on screen, everything is fine. However I must know when it's removed from the screen so that I can unregister `MyView` from the event handler.

In Obj-C this could be simply done in the `dealloc` method because when the screen changes the `UIViewController` is deallocated --> `MyView` is removed from it's superview and then `MyView` dealloc method is called.

In Monotouch I don't have this 'deterministic' flow anymore. I tried to put some print statements in the `UIViewController` and `MyView` destructors but they are never called (the reason is because the `MyView` is still registered for the event handler, since I don't know when/how to unregister it, it will never be deallocated).

Does anyone know what is the 'pattern' to handle such situations in MonoTouch? I think I'm missing a fundamental concept and getting into trouble developing my apps.

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT**
I'm editing my question because looks like the solution for my problem is using the [Weak Event Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx) but I didn't find an implementation for the MonoTouch platform.

Does anyone know how can I use the [Weak Event Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx) in MonoTouch ?

Comment: Try overriding `Dispose`. This might not work for your case though (the way it sounds). Let me know.

Comment: It might not work if he overrides Dispose on MyView, but it should work if he disconnects the handler in MyViewController's Dispose override.

Comment: @jstedfast @Greg Munn (below) suggested for me to disconnect/connect the event handler in the `ViewWillDisappear` and `ViewWillAppear` method pair. A similar situation would be to perform this on the `Constructor` and the `Dispose` methods? Will `Dispose` be invoked if `UIViewController` was captured by the event handler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to handle events is to unregister them in ViewWillDisappear and register them in ViewWillAppear. This means that you can't use anonymous methods though as you don't have a reference to the method to unregister it.

If that doesn't suit what you need, you can do something similar to this http://sgmunn.com/blog/2012/05/non-gcd-event-handlers/

Cheers.

Comment: `ViewWillAppear` and `ViewWillDisappear` sounds interesting but what if a ViewController wants to present a Modal View Controller (i.e.: to retrieve user information) and receive the results using an event handler? At the time the Modal View Controller is presented the root view controller will have it's `ViewWillDisappear`method invoked and thus will unregister itself for such events. That's the main point: I don't know which method to override to perform register/unregister tasks

Comment: `ViewDidUnload` is also not an option (its obsolete and isn't guaranteed to be always called when the View controller is closed)

Comment: @EduardoCoelho View A presents a view B modally -> In this case you'd have to keep a flag to know if B is modal. You can also check the value of PresentedViewController (it'll be the modal one).

Comment: I created a gist with a abstract UIViewController subclass that serves as a 'pattern' for registering/unregistering for events in UIViewController subclasses. https://gist.github.com/eduardocoelho/5044439 what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for weak events, you can try my "Messenger" implementation [here](https://github.com/jonathanpeppers/XPlatUtils/blob/master/XPlatUtils/Messenger.cs).

It is inspired by what is available in [TinyIoC](https://github.com/grumpydev/TinyIoC/), but I re-implemented it so it used less reflection, etc.