# Add/remove EventHandler for UIBarButtonItem

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uibarbuttonitem

One can define an `EventHandler` in the constructor:

```
UIBarButtonItem logoutButton = new UIBarButtonItem (UIBarButtonSystemItem.Stop, logoutButtonEventHandler);

private void logoutButtonEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs args){
    Console.WriteLine("Logout");
}
```

Is it possible to remove the `EventHandler` afterwards? Perhaps by not using an `EventHandler` at all and instead use the `Action`/`Target` properties of [`UIBarButtonItem`](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/UIKit.UIBarButtonItem/)? I don't find any examples. Only [anonymous methods](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/navigation_controller/add_a_nav_bar_right_button/) are used all the time.

How do you do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instantiate your object and then set the handler:

```
var logoutButton = new UIBarButtonItem (UIBarButtonSystemItem.Stop)
logoutButton.Clicked += logoutButtonEventHandler;
```

To remove it afterwards use the `-=` syntax:

```
 logoutButton.Clicked -= logoutButtonEventHandler;
```

Just beware of [commom pitfalls](http://bluetubeinc.com/blog/2013/7/memory-management-pitfalls-in-xamarin-ios-pitfall-2) when you do so because they may cause memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

UIBarButtonItem has [Clicked event](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/UIKit.UIBarButtonItem.Clicked/) so you can subscribe and unsubscribe to it.