# RemoveTarget from UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uigesturerecognizer, target-action

I've added an action as anonymous method to my gesture recognizer

```
UITapGestureRecognizer tapGesture = new UITapGestureRecognizer ();
tapGesture.AddTarget (() => HandleTap (tapGesture));
```

How can I remove the target? `UIGestureRecognizer.Token` is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RTFM](https://iosapi.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIGestureRecognizer+Token/) is true here:

> An instance of this class is returned when you invoke the UIGestureRecognizer's UIGestureRecognizer.AddTarget method. The AddTarget returns this token as a mechanism for later unsubscribing this particular action from the recognizer using the UIGestureRecognizer.RemoveTarget method.

```
UIGestureRecognizer.Token token = tapGesture.AddTarget (() => HandleTap (tapGesture));

if (token != null) {
    tapGesture.RemoveTarget (token);
}
```