# Clicked handler not executed for UIButton in UIBarButtonItem

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uibarbuttonitem

I want to have a custom button title in my toolbar. This is what I've used before.

```
UIButton someButton = UIButton.FromType (UIButtonType.System);
someButton.SetTitle ("My custom button title", UIControlState.Normal);
someButton.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Black, UIControlState.Normal);
someButton.SizeToFit ();
someBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem (someButton);

someButton.Clicked += someEventHandler;
```

The `Clicked` event is never thrown and so my event handler is not called. I want to be able to add (+=) and remove (-=) the event handler at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add your event onto the someBarButtonItem instead of the button, maybe the UIBarButtonItem is not forwarding touches correctly down to subviews?

Comment: You are right. I should add the event to `UIButton` and not to `UIBarButtonItem`. Now I use `someButton.TouchUpInside += someEventHandler;` and it seems to work.